# Python / Pandas; How to hold value of column until next event

Tags: python, pandas

I've been struggling with a problem for a while and haven't been able to find something similar elsewhere. I'm pretty new to Python so appologies if this is pretty straight forward.

So I have a series that I put into a pandas df:

```
series_ = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0]
df = pd.DataFrame(series_, columns = ['Values'])
```

The series can have two 'signal values':
Every time the series value is 1, I want the corresponding value to be 'YES'
If the value is 4, it should be 'NO'.

When the series is not 1 or 4, it should replicate the previous signal value (either 'YES' or 'NO') until the next signal value. I sadly can't find a formula that fills up these empty spots.

So what I currently have is my series ('Values') and the translation of these signal values in the column ('Modified'). I am trying to find a formula that will get me the column ('Expected'), a formula which basically replaces the 'UNDECLARED' values with either 'YES' or 'NO' based on the last available signal value.

[image]

Would appreciate all help!

Thanks in advance.

Tom

Comment: `trying to find a formula` - Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. You haven't shown us how you went from the original DataFrame to the example at the bottom of the post. Pandas has [excellant documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html).  Be careful of posting images:[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am certain, that there is a better way to do this but here is a quick and dirty solution, not sure if speed is important to you...

```
df['Expected']=df['Values'].replace(0,np.NaN).ffill().replace({1:'NO', 4: 'YES'}).fillna('UNDECLARED')
```

Comment: Alternatively you can also use `map` `df['Values'].map({1: 'YES', 4: 'NO'}).ffill().fillna('UNDECLARED')` :)